# how to increment argv

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, argv

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    int f1,flag,n;
    if(argc<3)
    {
        printf("Correct format: ./a.out <fileName> <string>\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    f1=creat(argv[1],0666);
    if(f1<0)
    {
        printf("Creatioon error\n");
        exit(f1);
    }
    n=strlen(argv[2]);
    printf("%d\n",n);
    while(n-->0)
    flag=write(f1,argv[2]++,1);
    if(flag<0)
    {
        printf("Write error\n");
        exit(flag);
    }
    close(f1);
    return 0;
}
```

here in    `flag=write(f1,argv[2]++,1);` why do we do    `argv[2]++` and why is the length of the text to be copied is 1??

Comment: Ask the author of the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The increment is because it's in a (stupid) loop:

```
while(n-->0)
  flag=write(f1,argv[2]++,1);
```

but your code isn't indented so it's a bit harder to see.

`argv[2]` is a `char *` pointing at the string entered as the third word on the command-line, so incrementing it steps it to the next character in the string.

This is bad code; it should be `write(fl, argv[2], n);` to write it all at once. Of course, the return value must still be inspected and the `write()` maybe looped to try again or resume if there is a partial write.

Comment: Like `for (size_t n, total = strlen(argv[2]); (n = write(f1, argv[2], total) > 0; argv[2] += n, total -= n) {}` (and hoist `total` out if you want error checking).

Answer (score 0):

The length is 1 because the 3rd argument of write is 1.

You probably want this:

```
/* write second command line argument to the file */
flag=write(f1, argv[2], strlen(argv[2]);
```

Comment: `write` may succeed having written as little as one byte.

Comment: sure it may succeed but it's more efficient to write the whole string with one write.

Comment: The point is that your code isn't correct unless you put it in a loop.

Comment: Because if less than the full array is written, you don't catch that... well, depending on how you meant your code to be integrated into the OP's code, I suppose.